# Зачем создавать несколько приложений в django?

Tags: python, django

Задался вопросом...А зачем создавать несколько приложений в django,для чего?Ну как бы я знаю,что это необязательно для все проектов,но все же почему?

Comment: Не забывайте ставить галку слева от ответа, если он решил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проект - это твой сайт, **mysite.ru**. В котором настраиваются настройки в файле `settings.py`, урлы в `urls.py`.
Приложения - это часть логики сайта, к примеру: **articles** - где предположим хранится всё что относится к статьям на твоём сайте, шаблонов в папке **templates**, описания модели в файле `models.py`, и вывода представления в `views.py`.
И количество **application (приложений)** в твоём проекте может быть очень много, к примеру корзины магазина, профиля пользователя, новостей, и тд. Что в своё очередь даёт возможность переносить **application** из проекта в проект.

[источник](https://qna.habr.com/q/373187)